# Is it possible to lock certain columns in laravel to prevent users from altering them with migrations?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to lock certain columns in some models to prevent the user from altering them using migrations. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Grant only specific permissions for those columns for a particular user on a table. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/allow-select-on-specific-column-only

Comment: Could you please elaborate the use case? What you are trying to do looks odd. There is probably a better way to achieve what you need since migrations are usually executed by system user such as root or www-data instead of laravel users

Comment: @Luciano I am planning to create a private composer package similar something like spatie permission. However I want to restrict the default columns created by myself and allow the users to add more columns only.

Comment: Another reason is that I am curious, what if the users like myself accidentally deletes a column from spatie permission? is there a way to prevent this from happening rather than to suggest to re add the column back?